# How to find and replace single quote in some string?

Tags: php, regex

Because assert — Checks if assertion is FALSE in php after 7.2 version  changed need using string as the assertion is DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.

And I want use `replace in path` php storm function with regex, changing all point where is it was, how it's look this is regular expression ?

example pioints:

```
assert('is_array($config)');
assert('is_string($location)');
assert('is_string($entityId)');
```

I just found and replace first quote, just like this 
`.*?(\bassert\('\b)[^$]*` replace to `assert(`. But how it be with last quote I don't know.

result must be

```
assert(is_array($config));
assert(is_string($location));
assert(is_string($entityId));
```

with first single quote I found solution, need find solution to last single quote

Any ides ?

Comment: What should the strings become?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We would better off starting with an expression with more boundaries, such as:

```
.*?(\bassert\b)\s*\(('|")\s*([^'"]*?)\s*('|")\s*\)\s*;
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/.*?(\bassert\b)\s*\((\'|")\s*([^\'"]*?)\s*(\'|")\s*\)\s*;/s';
$str = 'assert ("  is_string($entityId)") ;';
$subst = '$1($3);';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmsF0j/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tmsF0j/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: it's not what needed, because this expression resurn `assert('`, that's all, Atm I need remove last single quote and expression must return single quote from text where matches assert in first symbol possition

Answer (score 1):

One option to match a single quote only could be to make use of `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match. Make use of `\K` to forget what was currently matched and then match the single quote.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
(?:^.*?\bassert\(|\G(?!^))[^']*\K'(?=.*\);)
```

About the pattern

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^.*?\bassert\(` Match from the start of the string in a non greedy way until you encounter `assert(`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^']*\K'` Match 0+ times not `'`, forget what was matched and match `'`
- `(?=.*\);)` Assert what is on the right is a closing parenthesis and `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AC3gnn/1)

Another way could be to use 3 capturing groups, match the `'` that you want to remove and use the groups in the replacement:

```
^(.*?\bassert\()'([^']+)'(.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AC3gnn/2)